# Using Ember.JS store to query Laravel 8 REST API

Tags: ember.js, laravel-8

I'm developing a personal trading card DB in Ember.JS with a Laravel 8 REST API... for fun? Currently working on a page to add cards to my DB in bulk. The user will select what deck they want to add cards to and the respective deck's card checklist will be displayed, where I can select what cards will be added. I'm stuck on displaying the appropriate card's for their respective deck.

I'm using the ember package Service

```
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';
...
@service store;
```

Inside my controller, I'm calling an action that will update the variable/displayed cards.

```
@action updateModel() {
    let x = this.store.query('card', {
        year: {
            eq : yearVar
        }
    });
 ...
}
```

This is the error info:

```
Uncaught (in promise) 
Object { message: "Aborted", 
name: "AbortError", 
stack: "exports.DOMException@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:49690:28\nfetch/WHATWGFetch</xhr.onabort/<@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:49730:22\nsetTimeout handler*fetch/WHATWGFetch</xhr.onabort@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:49729:23\nEventHandlerNonNull*fetch/WHATWGFetch<@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:49728:11\ninitializePromise@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:47175:15\nPromise@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:47631:35\nfetch@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:49697:16\nexports.default@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:49801:30\n_fetchRequest@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:52788:16\najax@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:52753:35\nquery@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:52361:19\n_query/promise<@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:71800:61\ninvokeCallback@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:47150:17\nthen/<@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:47207:40\n@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:42711:62\ninvoke@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:41296:16\nflush@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:41211:19\nflush@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:41374:21\n_end@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:41815:34\nBackburner/this._boundAutorunEnd@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:41539:14\npromise callback*buildNext/<@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:41040:35\nflush@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:26782:5\n_scheduleAutorun@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:41981:14\n_ensureInstance@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:41972:14\nschedule@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:41665:19\n@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:42711:28\nthen@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:47207:14\n_query@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:71800:42\nquery@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:72905:32\nupdateModel@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/cam-card-comp.js:607:18\nEventListener.handleEvent*addEventListener@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:39057:15\ninstall@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:39194:23\ncommit/tag<@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:36926:25\ntrack@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:40488:7\ncommit@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:36924:42\ncommit@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:36999:19\ninTransaction@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:37019:13\n_renderRoots@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:6446:36\n_renderRootsTransaction@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:6490:14\n_renderRoot@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:6435:12\n_appendDefinition@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:6360:12\nappendOutletView@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:6350:12\ninvoke@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:41298:16\nflush@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:41211:19\nflush@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:41374:21\n_end@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:41815:34\nBackburner/this._boundAutorunEnd@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:41539:14\npromise callback*buildNext/<@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:41040:35\nflush@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:26782:5\n_scheduleAutorun@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:41981:14\n_end@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:41821:18\nBackburner/this._boundAutorunEnd@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:41539:14\npromise callback*buildNext/<@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:41040:35\nflush@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:26782:5\n_scheduleAutorun@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:41981:14\n_end@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:41821:18\nBackburner/this._boundAutorunEnd@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:41539:14\npromise callback*buildNext/<@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:41040:35\nflush@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:26782:5\n_scheduleAutorun@http://10.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:41981:14\n" }
vendor.js:41829:18
```

I checked the URL the ember app was sending to the API, it is as follows, and it's correct:

```
http:10.0.0.0:4000/cards?year[eq]=2022
```

Took this URL and pasted it into my browser, it successfully returned the appropriate checklist. This tells me I'm creating the query correctly and sending it correctly. Mozilla Firefox's inspector shows the network GET request was BLOCKED, and I'm given the EmberJS error.

Answer (score 0):

if request is blocked it could be CORS problem (by default it accept only same origin but in you case fornt-end served on 4200 and api on 4000), in laravel 8  check  `config/cors.php` and allow all origines * something like this `<?phpreturn['paths'=>['api/*'],'allowed_methods'=>['*'],'allowed_origins'=>['*'],'allowed_origins_patterns'=>[],'allowed_headers'=>['*'],'exposed_headers'=>false,'max_age'=>false,'supports_credentials'=>false,];`

Comment: Unfortunately, I have all origins allowed and I'm able to execute store.find and store.findAll() when loading models. After a long time of staring and reading, I think I'm not handling ember's order of operations correctly, or at least not handling the promises correctly. I've reverted to what I know best and that's filtering and sorting the entire list of cards I get from the model with embers sort and filter functions, instead of querying my API with parameters to return the list.